# how to change gridview row color based on condition in uwp c#?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, uwp, uwp-xaml

how to change gridview row color based on condition in uwp c#?

I want to highlight the gridview row based on my conditon.

Comment: sorry for late reply.. i have not try any code for this.. i have no idea regarding this..

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way to do this would be to put a Border around your `GridViewItem` and use a `ValueConverter` to choose the background color based on the current item.

First you define your value converter:

```
public class ItemToColorConverter: IValueConverter
{
    //this converts the item from your data source to the color brush
    //of the background of the row
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
    {
       //cast the value parameter to the type of item in your data source
       var yourValue = ( YourType )value;
       if ( yourValue > 10 ) //some condition you want to use to choose the color
       {   
          //highlight
          return new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Green );
       }
       else
       {
          //leave no background
          return new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Transparent );
       }
    }

    //you don't have to implement conversion back as this is just one-way binding
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you need to create a Application resource instance of the converter in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application ...>
   <Application.Resources>
      <converters:ItemToColorConverter x:Key="ItemToColorConverter" />
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Now use this converter in your `GridView` item `DataTemplate`:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding YourDataSource"}>
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ItemToColorConverter}">
            <!-- ... your content -->
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
   </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: i want change background color only those rows who having greater than 10 marks(condition).. but above soln is convert all rows in green color..

Comment: Thank you for reply.. but still i am not get my soln..i am searching something like RowDataBound in asp.net

Comment: You can modify it as needed. If you want to keep the background transparent, use Colors.Transparent in the SolidColorBrush constructor :-)

Comment: i want to highlight  some rows based on my condition else no color change.